# (Jmilne FT) Why must $f_3$ only have $\le 2$ irred factors of odd degree mod 5 for $-15f_1+10f_2+6f_3$ to have Galois group $S_n$?

Tags: galois-theory

Here is Example 4.33 (pages 55-56) from http://jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf:

> Select separable monic polynomials of degree $n$, $f_1,f_2,f_3$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that:
>
> (1) $f_1$ is irreducible modulo 2;
>
> (2) $f_2=(\textrm{degree 1})(\textrm{irreducible of degree }n-1)$ mod 3;
>
> (3) $f_3=(\textrm{irreducible of degree 2})(\textrm{product of 1 or 2 irreducible polynomials of odd degree}$) mod 5.
>
> Take
>   $$f=-15f_1+10f_2+6f_3.$$
>   Then
>
> (i) $G_f$ is transitive (it contains an $n$-cycle because $f\equiv f_1$ mod 2);
>
> (ii) $G_f$ contains a cycle of length $n-1$ (because $f\equiv f_2$ mod 3);
>
> (iii) $G_f$ contains a transposition (because $f\equiv f_3$ mod 5, and so it contains the product of a transposition with a commuting element of odd order; on raising this to an appropriate odd power, we are left with the transposition). Hence $G_f$ is $S_n$.

My question is: Why must $f_3$ have only 1 or 2 factors of odd degree?  In particular, I don't see why there can't be more than 2; it seems to me as if the same argument would hold if (for example) $f_3$ had 3 (irreducible) factors of odd degree.

Comment: It would, but that would complicate the proof. Why choose three factors when you could choose one?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown How would it complicate the proof?  In particular, would it be more complicated than in the case of 2 factors?  Whether you have 2, 3, or more factors, it seems like you would just multiply (or take the lcm of) the cycle lengths to get an appropriate odd power

Comment: You need to prove these factors exist. What's wrong with the following argument: "take $f_3$ to be the product of an irreducible quadratic and $n-2$ linear factors modulo $5$"?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Does something go wrong in that case?  Can you give an example of polynomials $f_1,f_2,f_3$ that satisfy the conditions (where $f_3$ is the product of an irred quadratic and $n-2$ linear factors mod 5) such that $f:=-15f_1+10f_2+6f_3$ does not have Galois group $S_n$?